# Categorical probability theory: Fritz' diagram categories

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, category-theory, functors

**1. Context**.
In the seventh chapter of his 2019 paper [A synthetic approach to categorical probability theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07021.pdf#page27) Tobias Fritz introduces certain diagram categories. Supposedly, these allow for a categorical approach to stochastic processes. Fritz illustrates this with an example — which I do not understand.

Consider the posetal category $\mathcal{D}=\mathbb{Z}$, where the objects are the integers and there is a morphism $n\rightarrow m$ if and only if $n\geq m$. Let $\mathcal{C}=\text{BorelStoch}$ be the category whose objects are standard Borel spaces and whose morphisms are Markov kernels between them. Note that the category $\mathcal{C}$ is a full subcategory of the Markov category $\text{Stoch}$ discussed in Chapter four of Fritz' paper. Next, consider the subcategory $\mathcal{C}_{\text{det}}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ which has the same objects as $\mathcal{C}$ but whose morphisms are the deterministic morphisms. In the case $\mathcal{C}=\text{BorelStoch}$, the deterministic morphisms can be identified with measurable maps between standard Borel spaces. Denote by $I$ the constant functor $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}_{\text{det}}$ that sends every integer to the singleton measurable space.

In chapter seven Fritz introduces the full subcategory $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ of the functor category $[\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C}]$. Its objects are functors $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}_{\text{det}}$. Fritz indicates a correspondence between morphisms $I\rightarrow X$ in this category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ (i.e. natural transformations) and stochastic processes with indexing set $\mathbb{Z}$.
He writes:

> The functors $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}_{\text{det}}$ can be identified with infinite diagrams of measurable spaces
> $$ \ldots \rightarrow X_{n+1}\rightarrow X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}\rightarrow \ldots$$ where all the maps involved are measurable functions. We think of each component $X_n$ as the space of joint values of a stochastic process over all times $t\leq n$, where the map $X_{n+1}\rightarrow X_n$ amounts to forgetting the value of the process at time $n+1$. A morphism $I\rightarrow X$ in $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ then assigns a probability measure to each of the measurable spaces $X_n$ in such a way that the projections $X_{n+1}\rightarrow X_n$ are measure-preserving; thus such a morphism exactly turns $X$ into a stochastic process.

**2. Questions**.

- How can a morphism $I\rightarrow X$ in the functor category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ be seen as a (discrete-time) stochastic process? Fritz spells out what the objects and morphisms in the functor category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ are in our case. This I understand. However, I fail to see how to relate these structures to stochastic processes. This might be related to the Daniell-Kolmogorov extension theorem — I don't see how, though.
- Conversely, how does a (discrete-time) stochastic process give rise to a morphism $I\rightarrow X$ in the functor category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$? My attempt at an explanation is given below.
- (In what sense) are these constructions inverses?
- What is meant by the following sentence?

> We think of each component $X_n$ as the space of joint values of a stochastic process over all times $t\leq n$, where the map $X_{n+1}\rightarrow X_n$ amounts to forgetting the value of the process at time $n+1$.

**3. Ideas**
Let $(Y_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a stochastic process with sample space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and state space $(S,\Sigma)$. For each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, define the set $X_n\colon =\{(Y_i(\omega))_{i\leq n}\ \vert \ \omega \in \Omega\}\subset \prod_{i\leq n}S$ and the projection $\pi_n\colon X_n\rightarrow X_{n-1}$ which deletes the $n$-th component. For each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, consider the image $S_n\colon =\operatorname{im}(Y_n)$. For each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, define the subspace $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_n\colon =\{A\cap S_n \ \vert \ A\in \Sigma\}$. Next, consider a pushforward measure on $(S_n,\Sigma_n)$, namely $\mu_n(A) \colon = P(\pi_n^{-1}(A))$ for $A \in \Sigma_n$. For each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, we obtain a probability space $(S_n,\Sigma_n,\mu_n)$. Next, we define a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ on the infinite product $\prod_{i\leq n}S_i$ as done [here](https://planetmath.org/InfiniteProductMeasure). Then we endow the pair $(\prod_{i\leq n}S_i, \mathcal{B})$ with the probability measure $\prod_{i\leq n}\mu_i$ as (again) defined [here](https://planetmath.org/InfiniteProductMeasure). Am I on the right track?

Comment: What is a "deterministic morphism"?

Comment: @FShrike: A morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ in a Markov category is called deterministic if $\Delta_Y \circ f=(f\otimes f)\circ \Delta_X$ holds. Here, $\Delta_X$ and $\Delta_Y$ denote the respective copy maps/comultiplications in the Markov category. You can think of this as follows: Copying and the applying $f$ to each copy separately yields the same result as first applying $f$ and then copying the result. In more informal terms (due to Paolo Perrone): "Randomness is doing the same thing twice and expecting different results." (The term "expected" seems a bit unfortunate in this context.)

Answer (score 1):

A previous version of the question implied that $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C})$ was notation for the functor category $[\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C}_\text{det}]$. This answer exists mostly to correct this misunderstanding, which I thought was the OP's main stumbling block. From the OP's feedback that seems not to be the case, so I might write another answer later answering their points in detail.

The important text is above propostion 7.1 (empahsis added)

> Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a Markov category and $\mathsf{D}$ an arbitrary small category. We then introduce another Markov category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathsf{D}, \mathsf{C})$. Its objects are defined to be functors $\mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{C}_\text{det}$, which we think of as diagrams with shape $\mathsf{D}$ of deterministic morphisms in $\mathsf{C}$, and its morphisms are natural transformations between these functors (**with not necessarily deterministic components**). We use notation $X = (X_d)_{d\in\mathsf{D}}$ for such functors, emphasizing their interpretation as diagrams.

This text is defining the category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C})$ - it's not just notation for the functor category $[\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C}]$ or $[\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C}_\text{det}]$.

The *objects* of $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C})$ are functors $\mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{C}_\text{det}$, which is why the maps in the diagram

$$ \ldots \rightarrow X_{n+1}\rightarrow X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}\rightarrow \ldots$$

are measurable functions and not Markov kernels. But the *morphisms* in $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathsf{D},\mathsf{C})$ are natural transformations in $\mathsf{C}$, not $\mathsf{C}_\text{det}$, so a morphism $I\to X$ is a family of Markov kernels (not measurable functions!) $I\to X_i$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake. That still does not explain the connection with stochastic processes, though.

Comment: @M.C. your idea in part 3 of your question is basically correct - I think if you look at the text again in light of this definition you should be able to make sense of it.

Comment: I don't, I am afraid. How does a morphism $I\rightarrow X$ in $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ give rise to a sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-indexed random variables?